# Integration tests code coverage report with OpenClover, Java and Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, clover, integration-testing

I am successful in deploying instrumented WAR(using [gradle-clover-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin)) on tomcat and db files are getting created when integration tests execute.

gradle-clover-plugin does not support report generation of code covered by integration tests. Please share if you have achieved it.

Below are the server logs generated when integration tests execute:

> [flushed per-test recording
>   (/home/user/workspace/path/to/submodule/build/.clover/clover.db-test1r8dacv75zui7_1v_1di977_jdd8p6lo.s)
>   ] [flushed per-test recording
>   (/home/user/workspace/path/to/submodule/build/.clover/clover.db-test1r8dacv75zui7_1v_8py5lk_jdd8p6lo.s)
>   ]
>
> Writing global coverage file
>   /home/user/workspace/prime-tracking/pilot-tracking/pilot-tracking-engine/build/.clover/clover.db-test8py5lk_jdd7iogiWriting
>   global coverage file
>   /home/user/workspace/path/to/submodule/build/.clover/clover.db-test1di977_jdd7rdyq
>   Writing global coverage file
>   /home/user/workspace/path/to/submodule/build/.clover/clover.db-testumozz6_jdd7iqkq

Comment: Have you considered using the [jacoco agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html)? This uses on-the-fly instrumentation so you don't need an instrumented war, you can use the same war you use in production

Comment: @lance-java: I will try jacoco agent. Do you have a link to documentation or example having steps to use it with gradle?

Comment: The [gretty plugin](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Code-coverage-support.html) has out of the box support for starting a servlet container with the correct jacoco jvm args. Or, you could determine a jacoco jvm arg string similar to [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-share/blob/master/build.gradle#L65) and add these jvm args when starting your servlet container

Comment: Thanks @lance-java for recommending jacoco agent. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find code coverage with Jacoco. As offline instrumentation is not required for it. I  am able to fetch coverage of manual and automated tests with Jacoco. Here are simple to set up jacoco for your project:

http://sdetsforsdets.com/2018/03/19/code-coverage-jacoco/

Integrate jacoco with Sonarqube for detailed analysis.